# Java - Generating XML data dynamically via Input records

Tags: java, xml

I have to generate the following format of XML using java:

```
<document>
   <creditDetails>
         <accountNo>123456</accountNo>
   </creditDetails>
   <creditDetails>
         <accountNo>123123</accountNo>
   </creditDetails>
   . 
   .
   .
   ...
</document>
```

Now, I have created the above provided XML using the Document.appendChild and relevant XML code.

When I have to create a new block of Credit Details, I have to create a new XML component which is a very bad practice.

I have lets say 15 records and I have iterated those records one by one to create a single xml format for all of them as provided in my question.

Can someone guide me? How I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

The correct way would be to use [JAXB (Java Architecture for XML Binding)](https://www.baeldung.com/jaxb).

Then you should have the following data classes:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "document")
public class Document {
  private List<CreditDetail> creditDetails = new ArrayList<>();

  public List<CreditDetail> getCreditDetails() {
    return creditDetails;
  }
}

public class CreditDetail {
  private int accountNo;
  public int getAccountNo() {
    return accountNo;
  }
  public void setAccountNo(int accountNo) {
    this.accountNo = accountNo;
  }
}
```

Now you can just create your account data in Java and the Marshaller will do the work for you:

```
Document doc = new Document();

CreditDetail creditDetail1 = new CreditDetail();
creditDetail1.setAccountNo(123456);
doc.getCreditDetails().add(creditDetail1);
CreditDetail creditDetail2 = new CreditDetail();
creditDetail2.setAccountNo(123123);
doc.getCreditDetails().add(creditDetail2);
// could make your classes a bit more pretty, e.g. Factory methods or constructor

JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Document.class);
Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
marshaller.marhaller(document, writer);

writer.toString() // gives your XML
```

Unfortunately JAXB is not included in the JDK since Java 11 so you have to add it in your dependency management.